# Violation of 1) normality of error terms, 2) heteroscedasticity and 3) spatially correlated error terms.Alternatives?

Tags: regression, least-squares, regression-coefficients, spatial, assumptions

I am using linear (Ordinary Least Squares) regression to estimate the coefficients and model fitness for vegetation in an ecological study. However, after model fit, tests showed that the linear regression violates 
1) normality of error terms 
2) is heteroscedastic (non-constant) variance of error terms and
3) likely spatially correlated error terms(non-indepedence). 
What alternative linear regression model should i use? Or how do i solve for these problems to meet the assumptions in regression?

Comment: I am quite new in spatial analysis, so I am not sure I am correct. I think you can transform your outcome variable to handle the normality problem (e.g. box-cox transformation). For spatial correlation and heteroscedasticity, you may need to specify your covariance structure when fitting model. Stationary and Isotropic Gaussian process might be a good start for you (it can handle spatial correlation, but surely not your final solution because it assumes homoscedasticity)

Comment: Actually, my residuals "look normal", although statistical tests(KSL test) suggest the data is from non-normal distributions. Also my standard deviations are 0.101 and 0.124 for mediansplit of the residuals. Can i assume normality & homoscedasticity? Any reference to quote?